# arabic fonts display in square symbols in barryvdh/laravel-snappy

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8, laravel-snappy

I am using `laravel-snappy` to convert a html page to pdf, but it is showing arabic text in square symbols in pdf body but the outline in arabic and this happen just in **production** like that:

[image]

But in **development** env works fine.

Any idea why?

Comment: See here if it helps: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy/issues/186

Comment: no i saw it before, didn't make any change

Answer (score 0):

You can add this as header in your html:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```